# What is RDWHAHB?

Tags: terminology

RDWHAHB. What is this curious acronym?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

RDWHAHB means: Relax Don't Worry Have A Home Brew.

Coined many years ago by the "Godfather" of homebrewing, [Charlie Papazian](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Charlie_Papazian).

This phrase has even populated urban culture: [Urban Dictionary](http://acronyms.thefreedictionary.com/RDWHAHB)

Find about more about this at the [American Homebrewers Association Website](http://www.homebrewersassociation.org/).

Get yourself a [bumpersticker](http://shop.beertown.org/brewers/product.asp?dept_id=&pf_id=5002_210&).

CHEERS!

Comment: The AHA link is dead. I fixed the Charlie Papazian link

Answer (score 3):

http://acronyms.thefreedictionary.com/RDWHAHB\

*Acronym    Definition
RDWHAHB Relax, Don't Worry, Have A Homebrew*